# Is there a way to strengthen individual pieces?

Tags: piece-information, bionicle

Is there a way to strengthen fragile parts? Say for example the lime green socket joints from 2007? Or the 2008-2010 socket joints? I would like to know if there is a possible way to do so?

I am interested in preventing the breakage of a piece, while still keeping the ability to pose the figure

Comment: Are you interested in preventing the breakage of a part or creating a joint that can take more weight before bending?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as once the socket balls are worn out, you can't exactly make it unworn.

Answer (score 1):

Those joints are based solely on friction, which comes from:

- the "bite" of the socket - how rigid the containing socket is
- the rigidity = non-elasticity of the ball
- the shape of the ball
- the relative friction between the two surfaces

The old plastic gets weaker with time, which rules out fixing the first two causes.

The shape of the ball would be pretty hard to fix; also the shape is not likely to have changed much.

This leaves the friction itself. So what you could do:

- spray an adhesive on the ball to make it tackier
- glue the joint in place (KRAGLE!!)